# How to use containsLocation in Google maps geometry library.

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am trying to use the `containsLocation` from the Google geometry library, but can't get it to work...

```
var point = new google.maps.LatLng(51.331, 3.538);
var poly = [
 new google.maps.LatLng(51.401818509550615, 3.547626782103622),
 new google.maps.LatLng(51.397574277049365, 3.563607598960424),
 new google.maps.LatLng(51.398540111384975, 3.567880788749134),
 ... // it is a lot bigger
];

if(google.maps.geometry.poly.containsLocation(point, poly) == true) {
 alert("yes");
}
```

The Javascript console gives an error, but that points to a function in Google's lib. So I assume the problem should lie somewhere in this function.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Oke, stupid me

I was wrong using all the coords as an array, I had to use the created polygon object.

```
var polyOptions = {
 ...
}

draw = new google.maps.Polygon(polyOptions);
draw.setMap(map);

if(google.maps.geometry.poly.containsLocation(point, draw) == true) {
 alert("yes");
}
```

Comment: When I do this I get the error `Object [object Object] has no method 'get'`

Comment: I am not sure, but i believe this was for API version 2. It did work back then...

Answer (score 5):

i had the same problem `([object Object])`, I could solve that creating the polygon variable like that:
`draw = new google.maps.Polygon({paths:polyOptions});`

Then the problem disappeared.