# Add a marker and find it's overlay name

Tags: jquery, google-maps-api-3, kml, jquery-ui-map

I am using [jquery-ui map](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-ui-map/) plugin to manipulate some maps

I am using overlays from a kml file and afterwards I am adding a marker, my goal is to see in which overlay's territory the marker was added
Any ideas? My code can be found here

http://jsfiddle.net/theodore/twGHC/268/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Proof of concept](http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/v3_geoxml3_pointInPoly_linkto.html)

Uses:

- geoxml3 to parse the (your) KML and add it to the map as native Google Maps API v3 objects
- the geocoder to place a marker (for convenience), you didn't specify your method
- the Google Maps API v3 geometry library to determine which polygon contains the marker

Based off of [this Google Maps API v2 example](http://www.geocodezip.com/collection-map2e.html), which was [ported to the Google Maps API v3](http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/v3_collection-map2e.html).

Answer (score 0):

It's been tough to find, but here it is. You should use containsLocation , methods of poly* namespace. ([poly](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#poly)).

Quoting #Neograph734

```
var polyOptions = {
 ...
}

draw = new google.maps.Polygon(polyOptions);
draw.setMap(map);

if(google.maps.geometry.poly.containsLocation(point, draw) == true) {
 alert("yes");
}
```

See [how-to-use-containslocation-in-google-maps-geometry-library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10836559/how-to-use-containslocation-in-google-maps-geometry-library)

Please, note that polygons have events. So if in your actual application, the marker is added by the user, use the click event from the polygons ([Polygon](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Polygon))